# Date and Time for Contact form 7 in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, contact-form, timepicker, contact-form-7

I am creating a custom reservation form on Revolution Slider in wordpress ...I need two inputs from the user Date and time separatly...In contact form 7 there is no field for time.I want date and time picker in my contact form 7.

Please guide me how can i do this in contact form 7.

**Here is the field which is not supported on contact form 7:**

```
[datetime date-arrival  class:arrival-datetime]
```

Answer (score 3):

here's what I did for the same issue.

```
[select* appt-hour include_blank "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12"]
[select* appt-min include_blank ":00" ":15" ":30" ":45"]
[select* appt-ampm include_blank "am" "pm"]
```